# Make backend url domain different from frontend url domain

Tags: magento2, frontend, url, backend

How to make different URLs for website frontend domain URL and admin domain URL for Magento 2?

currently, this is how I access my Magento 2 site:

```
frontend: https://magento.zzz
backend: https://magento.zzz/admin
```

I have another server with different where I reserve a subdomain as an access to my Magento 2 website backend for later.

```
new backend: https://adm.businness.zzz
```

Is it possible to set up the backend URL only to above URL and how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

This is a default feature in Magento2 -

1) Set cookie domain as .website.com from

> Store > Configuration > General > Web

2) Set Admin URL as the domain you want to set from

> Store > Configuration > Advanced > Admin

3) Set URL as working from the server side.

Make sure the cookie domain is functional as it can cause issues with login on browsers.